# Populate data in text field based on input provided in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to populate data in text filed based on given input.Below the code i am working on.

emp_form.html.erb

```
        '<%= f.label "Name:"%> <%= f.text_field :emp_name %>
        <%= f.label "Emp Id:" %> <%= f.text_field :emp_id %>
        <%= f.label "Roll:" %> <%= f.text_field :emp_roll %>'
```

If i am entering employee name in text field,it has to fetch emp_id and emp_roll value from sqlite data base and populate its value in respective text fields in the same form. How to implement this?

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Raja I have created a sample application for your problem below is the link for code on GitHub

> [Auto populate form values for search](https://github.com/swazruby786/Autopopulate)

[image]

I have written a simple ajax call for fetching the employee details based on the user typing the name on name field if values found that ajax will assign the values to the specified field.
First, you need to create an employee after taking the clone of code.

Comment: Welcome @RajaPandian

Comment: Are these exactly you want?

Comment: Hi Mohammad- I need to check  employee details are already available in data base or not and populate the same.For that if i enter employee id in text field,it has to fetch and show employee name and roll value in respective text fields.If not,i can show pop up "No records Matches"

Comment: You just need to change some code in controller and js for the same It is easy to please do it by your site

Comment: I am new to ruby.If you have any samples or any links for this,please share.

Comment: Give me 10 minutes

Comment: @RajaPandian Please access the above link otherwise link be expired in another hour.

Comment: yes Mohammad.Instead of search i need to insert data.Can you share latest code.I will check here.Thanks

Comment: You don't need to click on search button just type in any field it will automatically auto populate @RajaPandian i have pushed the code in the git please take a clone from there and approved my question as green

Comment: I have not covered all the scenario i have build it for your basic requirements

Comment: Getting error -Couln't find Employee with id=search

Comment: Please create the employees first

Comment: How to approve Mohammad.Is there any approve link will be there?

Comment: It showing only look up and inspect option when I do right click

Comment: I need one more help

Comment: Ok Sure Mohammad